# Needed help automating Extjs grid using webaii

Tags: gridview, automation, extjs, web-testing

We are extensively using webaii as our functional automation tool with great success, but we are now facing problems automating extjs grid types using webaii. Could anyone who has overcome this issue in webaii or watin or watir provide inputs on this.

Comment: I haven't had any problems testing the Ext grid with WebAii. Exactly what problems are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Look into Ext.ux.Autogrid

http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=10951